# Gradient with modified alpha doesn't fill whole page

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a gradient that fills my whole page - I've managed to have my gradient fill the complete page, however after dimming the gradient by changing the alpha variable, I've noted an inconsistency - the main portion of the page looks fine, but as soon as I scroll down, there's an issue with the dimming - the darker area of the gradient doesn't spread to the lower portion of the page, as seen below:

[Image is linked since I don't have high enough rep](https://olivernichol.co.uk/images/chrome_zeNHQOgAgn.png)

The CSS code is admittedly a mess after trying a number of solutions, but it is shown below:

```
html {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: rgb(54,174,0);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(54,174,0,1) 0%, rgba(55,0,174,1) 100%);
}
```

how can I ensure that the alpha modification covers the whole page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is an issue with the alpha modification.

You have the sub-properties for the background written above the main `background` property, the bottom `background` property will overwrite the above properties. Mainly the `background-attachment` is what's causing the issue.

The `css` should look like this:

```css
html {
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
}
body {
            margin: 0px;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            /*background: rgb(54,174,0);*/
            /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
            /*background-size: cover;*/
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(54,174,0,1) 0%, rgba(55,0,174,1) 100%);
            background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The commented lines are redundant as the property is either overwritten or set to the default.